# Firebase Cloud function is unable to write a document after using paypal sdk

Tags: javascript, firebase, paypal, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am having problems with this function after I call a get order paypal function. It successfully gets the order details and write it to the console. However after that, it is supposed to write to a Firestore document but it doesnt do that. There is no error on the functions log only that it started and executed the functions. If I remove the paypal function it then can write to documents so I know that code works. I just dont know what I am messing up. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Import and initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

paypal => configured here 


exports.createRecord = functions.firestore.document('messages/{messageId}').onCreate(
async (snapshot) => {


      var orderId = "3L62701538009611M";

      paypal.order.get(orderId, function (error, order) {
         if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return false;

         } else {
            console.log("Get Order Response",JSON.stringify(order));

            var userObject = {
                 displayName : 'BarryAllen',
                 email : 'FMA@Speedster.com',
             };

           return admin.firestore().doc('paid/docnametest').set(userObject)

    }

   });


 });
```

function logs

```
5:25:50.643 PM
checkWork
Function execution took 3559 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
5:25:47.516 PM
createRecord
Function execution took 236 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
5:25:47.281 PM
createRecord
Function execution started
5:25:47.085 PM
checkWork
Function execution started
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a promise that resolves when all the asynchronous work is complete.  Right now, the function is returning nothing, which means it will terminate immediately and the call to paypal will but shut down.  The return statement inside the callback function isn't returning a promise to the top-level function.

What you will need to do is "[promisify](https://javascript.info/promisify)" the call to paypal, as they currently don't support promises (unless you want to use their 2.0 beta).

If you promisify, it will look something like this, which you will probably want to change based on what you really want to do with the response from paypal:

```
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject)) => {
    paypal.order.get(orderId, function (error, order) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Get Order Response",JSON.stringify(order));
            resolve(order);
        }
    }
})
return p.then(order => {
    var userObject = {
        displayName : 'BarryAllen',
        email : 'FMA@Speedster.com',
    };

    return admin.firestore().doc('paid/docnametest').set(userObject).then
})
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. I have been banging my head on this for the last 2 days. Their 2.0 beta looks very nice lol I'll give that a try but after spending all my time to get this to work I might end up sticking with your corrected version. Thank you for your help.